# Handling Double Quotes when importing CSV file to SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv, double-quotes

I'm trying to import some CSV files into SQL using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. I came across an error where some of the values contained two double quotes at the end e.g. `GIG L SHAPIRO GU A""`. The Text Qualifier is already be set to `"`, so I'm not sure how to import these files.

Comment: A doubled quote should be treated as a single quotation mark contained in the text value.

Comment: It doesn't sound like your CSV file has been serialized correctly, in other words it's not a valid CSV file. If it's not compliant with [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) there's not much you can do. Either: (1) hand-edit the file to make it compliant, or (2) fix the process writing the file so that it encodes data correctly and regenerate it.